# What is the use of %include docker file?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am having a docker file which has following line in it

```
%include=../doxygen
```

If i try to run the docker command using this docker file, it gives me error

```
unknown instruction: %INCLUDE=../DOXYGEN
```

what is the purpose of `%include` in dockerfile?
is there anything that in need to pass in docker command to make it run?

Comment: Somply "%include" does not exist.

Comment: Someone might have set up a pipeline in your organisation with a preprocessor that can handle `%include`. See if you can find a shell script that builds the image.